# How to batch rename files via Terminal using the file's date as filename?

Tags: terminal, bash, file, macos

I have a bunch of photos and videos from different sources and want to normalize the file names using Terminal. I looked at a bunch of different tools from [NameChanger](https://mrrsoftware.com/namechanger/) to Automator and Finder itself. NameChanger does not allow more than one action at a time and Finder and Automator won't allow me to set the date format with a format string.

I've been playing around with a few bash functions and found that

```
stat -f "%Sm" -t "%Y-%m-%d %H.%M.%S" file.ext
```

produces the date time format I'm after.

Yet I found that

```
for file in *.*
do
    mv "$file" echo stat -f "%Sm" -t "%Y-%m-%d %H.%M.%S" "$file"
done
```

returns

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
```

I'm not really proficient with bash scripting so excuse any incompetence in the examples above.

What I want to do is remove all of the base name of the file (everything before .jpg) and replace it with the date and time format I got from `stat` earlier.

For example:

```
20160708_151344000_iOS.jpg   --> 2016-07-08 15.13.44.jpg
WP_20140915_02_03_15_Raw.jpg --> 2014-09-15 02.03.15.jpg
```

How do I need to do this?

Comment: Do you want the moved filename to be created from the result of the `stat` _command_ in your OP, or from information within the filename itself?

Comment: I want to read the date value of the file from the file system and use that as the file name instead. After I posted the question though, I noticed that the file system date, EXIF date and the date that already is in the file name (non-normalized) differ from each other for some files. But being able to do the rename from the file system date alone is useful to me nonetheless in case I only have the command line to work with.

Comment: Are you sure you really want `*.*`?  In DOS this matches all files but in Bash (and generally all Unix shells) it matches all file names which contain a literal dot.

Comment: Good point but how do I need to rephrase that condition of the loop so everything after the dot is a file name extension?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
for f in *.*; do 
    echo mv "$f" "$(stat -f '%Sm' -t '%Y-%m-%d %H.%M.%S' "$f").${f##*.}"
done
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
for f in *.*; do echo mv "$f" "$(stat -f '%Sm' -t '%Y-%m-%d %H.%M.%S' "$f").${f##*.}"; done
```

In either case, remove the `echo` *command* after testing.

The `${f##*.}` portion of the *command* get the *extension* of `$f` so you can use the *glob* `*.*` vs. using an *extension* in the `for f in`, i.e. `for f in *.*` vs. `for f in *.jpg`

Answer (score 3):

```
for f in *.jpg; do
    echo mv "$f" "$(stat -f '%Sm' -t '%Y-%m-%d %H.%M.%S' "$f")".jpg
done
```

Remove the `echo` once you are sure that the command looks ok.